# ExtJS 5.0 , getting an error during viewModel.linkTo() call , due to model namespace

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a model that is within a domain folder i:e

```
app
   |--model
         |--domain1
                   |--ApplicationInfoModel
                   |--AddressModel
                   |--ProducerInfoModel
                   |--CarrierInfoModel
                   |--ApplicantInfoModel
                   |....
         |--domain2
                   |
                   |--AddressModel
                   |....
```

Now when I am trying to load the data dynamically using viewModel's linkTo

```
   requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox',
    'RA.model.domain1.ApplicationInfoModel',
    'RA.model.domain1.ApplicantInfoModel'        
    ],
    ....
    ....
    ....
    init:function()
    {
         this.getViewModel().linkTo('applicationData',
         {            
             reference:"ApplicationInfoModel",
             id:'appl-0000001',                     
             autoLoad:true
         }); 
     }
```

I am getting an error as

```
       [E] Ext.app.ViewModel.getRecord(): Invalid model name:                
       ApplicationInfoModelUtil.js:Util.js:710 
       Objectmsg: "Invalid model name: ApplicationInfoModel"
       sourceClass: "Ext.app.ViewModel"
       sourceMethod: "getRecord"
```

Any, suggestions???

Edit

My Base model that all my model extends from.

```
Ext.define('RA.model.Base', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int'
}],
schema: {
    namespace: 'RA.model',
    urlPrefix:'app/model',
    proxy: {
        url: '{prefix}/{entityName}',
        pageParam: '',
        startParam: '',
        limitParam: ''
    }
}
});
```

Edit 2 :

If I include the reference as either:

```
reference:'domain1.ApplicationInfoModel',

-- or --

reference:'RA.model.domain1.ApplicationInfoModel',
```

I get the below error , which happens when it tries to pull the associated model under the same domain.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ra-ui/js/app/model/domain1.ApplicantInfoModel?_dc=1417096649804 404 (Not Found)
```

the assoicaiton is as below:

```
 Ext.define('RA.model.domain1.ApplicationInfoModel', 
 {
requires:['RA.model.domain1.ProducerInfoModel',
          'RA.model.domain1.CarrierInfoModel',
          'RA.model.domain1.ApplicantInfoModel'
          ],    
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty:'appid',
fields:[{
            name:'appid',type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'producer',
            reference:'ProducerInfoModel'
        },
        {
            name:'carrier',
            reference:'CarrierInfoModel'
        }           
        ],
hasMany:[       
    {           
        name:'applicants',          
        model:'RA.model.domain1.ApplicantInfoModel' 
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fully qualified model name.

Comment: I had tried that but , it would give me the error. = "GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/js/app/model/domain1.ApplicantInfoModel?_dc=1417060630545 404 (Not Found). "

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using the fully qualified model name, you can also configure the schema with a namespace (basically a prefix that goes in from the of the model name). From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Schema):

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.models.Base', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

   schema: {
     namespace: 'MyApp.models'
   }
 });
```

where `MyApp.models.Base` gets used as the parent class for your own models.

Comment: My schema is already uses the Base (sorry about not including that part of the code) the problem is with the need to add another domain layer nesting.

Comment: Okay. Well, with that namespace, and your model class names, use `reference: "domain1.ApplicationInfoModel"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a mistype, but you don't have an `RA.model.domain1.ApplicationInfoModel` in your domain folder.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. My whole code works if I don't separate my models into different domain folders.